# MYSQL natural sorting not behaving as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Natural sorting isn't behaving as expected on a query. I don't understand why. Having looked at this site http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/ , the method works for the most part. However, the alpha part of the 'code' means sorting occurs in an odd way.

Result

```
M1
..
M3
P1
..
P3
M10
..
M19
P10
..
P19
```

Expected

```
M1
..
M3
M10
..
M19
P1
..
P3
P10
..
P19
```

Code

```
'SELECT * FROM stock ORDER BY LENGTH(code), code';
```

Comment: So you're asking why it's behaving this way?

Comment: Sorry.. it has fried my brain. I am indeed asking why it's behaving like it is, and how to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort first by the length of the field. Of course that mixes the result in the wrong way. Try splitting the alphanumeric values and the numbers

```
SELECT * FROM stock 
ORDER BY substr(code, 1, 1), 
         substr(code, 2, 99) * 1
```

`*1` converts the string into a number. You could also use `cast(substr(code, 2, 99) as signed)`

Comment: That works great, thanks. However, I have a mixed set of alphas in a code, so 'P12' as well as 'PD12'. How do I factor that into it?